# Echo if the date is 24 hours before the required date

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I don't know what to put in search bar since I have no idea what to call it so, my bad if I have duplicate topic.

I seriously don't know how to put this but, I'll give an example.

Let's say, there's an event on **January 20, 2013 09:30:00**. Today's date is **January 11, 2013 15:25:00**.

I want to echo something a day before the event on January 20, 2013. (**24 Hours before the Event**)

It's like on January 19, 2013 I will receive or echo something that should remind me that tomorrow is the event takes place.

Well I have this code that I'm working on but still, it feels so wrong.

```
$start_ts = strtotime("2013-01-10 20:15:00"); //
$now_ts = strtotime("now");
$result_ts = $start_ts - $now_ts;
$reminder = ( 60 * 24 ) * 60; // 24 hours period

if ($result_ts <= $reminder) {
    echo "Today's a date before the event day";
} else {
    echo "Event is already finished";
}
```

**The output is:**

[image]

It should echo "**Event is already finished**"

To be honest, I'm losing my track here. Hope you guys help me, would be glad though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the magic:

```
if ($result_ts <= $reminder && $result_ts > 0) { //blah blah }
```

Comment: Wouldn't have thought that it would worked though. Thanks! But, I don't understand it. If the Date today is January 11, 2013, then changed the $start_ts into January 12, 2013, it echoed Today's the day before the event day, but if I changed it to January 13, 14, 15 or so why did it still worked? Since the "$result_ts > 0" and it should give positive values right? the Date is greater than 11.

Comment: Ohh! I already get it. I experimented a bit. Thanks a lot though. a very very very big help from you. :)